# cloud one's judgement vs. crowd one's judgement

Tags: expressions

> They let their emotion ***crowd their judgment***.
>
> Don't let your personal feelings ***cloud your judgement***.

I've seen the both expressions. Do they mean the same?

Since Stephie asked, here is the actual sentence.

> "People are emotional, they've heard the story, they feel
>   compassionate, and rather than using their logic to support or give,
>   ***they let their emotion crowd their judgment***."

(*[Crowdfunding and the downside of helping needy strangers](http://www.cbc.ca/news/business/crowdfunding-and-the-downside-of-helping-needy-strangers-1.2983208)*, CBC news, March 7 2015)

Comment: Pretty sure **crowd** is just people mis-understanding the **actual** phrase, *cloud one's judgement*.

Comment: There are zero results on the Ngram for "crowd". https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cloud+your+judgement%2C+crowd+your+judgement&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccloud%20your%20judgement%3B%2Cc0

Comment: While I am inclined to agree with @Catija, do you have an actual source for your quote with "crowd"?

Comment: In case you're curious, these are often called *eggcorns* or *oronyms* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn

Comment: In that example, the news source is directly quoting the speaker. They're not using the phrase themselves.

Comment: @ Catija   Thank you for the additional information of Wikipedia.  You made my day with "acorn" and "egg corn" !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple things going on here.

First off, I don't believe *to crowd your judgement* is an actual phrase.  I think it's a misstating of the correct phrase:

> to cloud your judgement

There is a concept (in English at least) of an *[eggcorn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn)* or *oronym*, which is a commonly misunderstood phrase:

> In linguistics, an eggcorn is an idiosyncratic substitution of a word or phrase for a word or words that sound similar or identical in the speaker's dialect (sometimes called oronyms). The new phrase introduces a meaning that is different from the original, but plausible in the same context, such as "old-timers' disease" for "Alzheimer's disease".

Note that it **is** still *plausible*... *crowd your judgement* could be something... as a native English speaker I **get** what they mean.

Which is why I think they may be conflating *cloud your judgement* with something like *stand out from the crowd*, which is an idiom that sort of [means the opposite](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stand+out+from+the+crowd) if you think of it:

> makes your idea *stand out from the crowd*

means that you're making the ideas prominent and more noticeable.

> emotion *clouds their judgement*

Means that the judgement is obscured and made difficult to make the *correct* decision.

Also note that the **subject** of the conversation in that article is ***crowd***funding.  This could even be a simple slip of the tongue... or something like a [Freudian slip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freudian_slip)... but without the psychological connotations.